# Appsync update functions lagging my application

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, aws-appsync, aws-amplify

I am building a react native project with aws-appsync for offline capability. but when my cache size increase and records increase to 5000(can we increase in millions) my application is lagging while updating to local cache.
Is the any way to overcome this problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52862441/react-native-aws-appsync-maximum-data-storage. although it's unanswered at the time of this comment